# Event binding for input type 'date' using knockout JS

Tags: knockout.js

I need to fire a event when user click on datetime picker. I use Knockout JS for binding. when I use click event its fire before user select a date

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" data-bind='value:BillingDate,valueUpdate: "input",enable:canChange,click:$root.UpdateServerData' />
```

Comment: Have you tried subscribing to the change event of your model's observable value instead?

Comment: refer to the "Explicitly subscribing to observables" section: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html

Answer (score 0):

It does work properly in the sense that "click event is fired as soon as the user clicks the element".

What you are looking for is probably a subscription to the change event of the observable.
In your viewmodel do something like :

```
BillingDate.subscribe(function(newValue){
// this is called every time the value changes
})
```